# tinymce loses caret position

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a tinymce custom button, which toggles an emoticons div beside a textarea.

```
onclick : function() {
  ed.focus();
  $('#my-input').toggleClass('with-emoticons');
  $('#emoticons').toggleClass('emo-visible');
}
```

When I click the button, the emoticons div has revealed, but the caret goes from the end to the start of my text.

How can I preserve the carets position while clicking the custom button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a bookmark

```
onclick : function() {
  ed.focus();

  var bookmark = ed.selection.getBookmark();

  $('#my-input').toggleClass('with-emoticons');
  $('#emoticons').toggleClass('emo-visible');

  ed.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark); 
}
```

The bookmark-type used here is a html bookmark which represents a non-visible span in the editor html. The getBookmark function is able to produce non-html bookmarks too. For this you may call  `ed.selection.getBookmark(2, true);` For more information on tinymce bookmarks have a look at the [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.getBookmark).